# Как объединить моё приложение

Tags: javascript, php, c#

Всем привет.
У меня на данный момент есть следующая ситуация. Есть приложение на C#, которое в реальном времени считывает определенные данные с прибора по COM порту, затем записывает их в базу данных (для этого установлен локальный сервер MAMP). Затем, с помощью PHP, JS, HTML происходит опрос этой базы данных и информация из неё отображается в браузере в виде необходимого графика (или мнемосхемы).
Получается, что для запуска данной системы необходимо запустить приложение C#, запустить локальный сервер, и открыть нужный HTML-файл.
Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какие-то сценарии, как это можно автоматизировать?

Comment: Запуск обернуть в службу, допустим. Страничку сделать стартовой в браузере. И еще можно не выключать сервер и не закрывать страницу )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сценарий здесь очень простой: называется командный файл. В нём пишите запуск приложений по очереди. Сам командный файл может запускаться из "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" или из планировщика задач по событию "регистрация пользователя в системе".